# How to use autoplot in R to plot rotated components?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm using the autoplot function in R (from the ggfortify package) to plot the first two components of a PCA, like this, using the iris dataset as an example:

```
data<-iris
data_dims<-(data[, 1:4])
data$Species<-as.factor(data$Species)
plot1<-autoplot(prcomp(data_dims, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE), data = data, colour = 'Species', frame = TRUE)
```

However, I'm wondering if anyone could help me to plot the rotated solution instead? I know to get the rotated solution like this:

```
pcompanalysis<-prcomp(data, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

pcompanalysis_rot <- varimax(pcompanalysis$rotation)
```

However, I'm unsure how to then use this rotated solution in the autoplot() function?

Edit: Examples are now using the iris dataset to allow reproduction.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to make this a question that folks can more easily help with, including how to post a sample of your data

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, the examples now use the iris dataset and are reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibile solution:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(pracma)

# Generate a dataset
set.seed(1234) 
n <- 20
p <- 25
ncomp <- 2
data_dims <- matrix(rnorm(n*p),nrow=n)
data <- data.frame(data_dims, Species=cut(runif(n), breaks=4))

# Perform PCA and calculate varimax rotated scores
pca.obj <- prcomp(data_dims, center=T, scale=T)
rawLoadings <- pca.obj$rotation[,1:ncomp] %*% diag(pca.obj$sdev, ncomp, ncomp)
varimax.obj <- varimax(rawLoadings)
rotatedLoadings <- varimax.obj$loadings

# Create a prcomp object with varimax rotated scores
pca_obj <- list(sdev=pca.obj$sdev, rotation=t(varimax.obj$rotmat), 
              center=NULL, scale=NULL, x=scale(pca.obj$x[,1:ncomp]))
name.pcs <- paste0("PC",1:ncomp)
dimnames(pca_obj$rotation) <- list(name.pcs,name.pcs)
dimnames(pca_obj$x) <- list(rownames(data_dims),name.pcs)
class(pca_obj) <- "prcomp"

plot1 <- autoplot(pca_obj, data=data, colour='Species', 
                  frame=TRUE, variance_percentage=F)
plot1
```

For more details see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/how-to-compute-varimax-rotated-principal-components-in-r).

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to scale this up to my actualy data (with 25 rating dimensions), but am getting the following error. Error in as.matrix(apply(pca_dims, 2, scale)) %*% varimax.rot : 
  non-conformable arguments

Wondering if you might be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I really appreciate you going through the trouble! Your code works with the sample data you generated; however, it still gives the same error with my data. However, I realized that the two matrices have a different number of columns when running the code on my data (data_dims has the expected 25; varimax.rot has only 20). Any idea on how to solve this, or why it is emerging?

Comment: I tried only taking the first twenty columns for the purpose of multiplication–is that a potential way to deal with that? See here: https://pastebin.com/HVsM1s5v

However, I now get the following error: Error in scale.default(data, center = FALSE, scale = 1/scale) : 
  length of 'scale' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thanks again for all of the help!

Comment: Thanks Marco! Just to double check, I've notied that the plot looks the same before and after rotation, is this to be expected? If not, I've pasted my attempt to adopt your code to my dataset, maybe I went wrong somewhere? https://pastebin.com/hLrZeJL5